# Why doesn't "total" from ls -l add up to total file sizes listed?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command, prompt

Why is the **total** in the output of `ls -l` printed as `64` and not `26078` which is the total of all files listed?

```
    $ ls -l ~/test/ls
    total 64
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root   15276 Oct  5  2004 a2ps.cfg
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root    2562 Oct  5  2004 a2ps-site.cfg
    drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  2  2007 acpi
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root      48 Feb  8  2008 adjtime
    drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 Feb  2  2007 alchemist
```

Comment: @LIU Qingyuan Secondly, this q shows multiple failures in interface.
1) `-l` is set to show total in cryptic way that almost no one needs. But `-lh` is what you need 99.9% of time. So why not make `-l` in MB and `-lAlmostNeverNeeded` in blocks?
2) no total in `--help`
3) no total in `man`
4) let us promote time waste: look in `--help`, go to `man`, remember `info`, read more.
(if you are on windows portable bash doesn't include man nor info, so you need to google for it like I am doing now.)
Finally on SO: let us punish native human questions. We reward endles readings of bad manuals.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can find the definition of that line in the `ls` documentation for your platform. For `coreutils` `ls` (the one found on a lot of Linux systems), the information can be found via `info coreutils ls`:

> For each directory that is listed, preface the files with a line
>        `total BLOCKS', where BLOCKS is the total disk allocation for all
>        files in that directory.

Comment: Funnily enough, `man ls` on my system does not mention that line, but `info coreutils ls` does. How comes `man ls` and `info coreutils ls` have different information about the same command? Why isn't `ls` just documented once? Having two different documentations for the same command seems like set up for failure.

Comment: `info` docs for coreutils stuff are often more detailed than the man pages. That's why they have a note at the end of each man page referring you to the info section for more details.

Comment: Ah. I executed `info ls` and it to give the same output as `info coreutils ls`. What does the argument `coreutils` do?

Comment: @Mat I've revised the question in hopes it can be reopened. Hopefully you can vote along...

Answer (score 50):

## The Formula:  What is *that* number?

> total *int* = Sum of **(physical_blocks_in_use) * physical_block_size/ls_block_size)** for each file.
>
> **Where:**
>
> - `ls_block_size` is an **arbitrary environment variable** (normally 512 or 1024 bytes) which is freely modifiable with the
>     `--block-size=<int>` flag on `ls`, the `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` GNU
>     environment variable (to get 512-byte units), or the `-k` flag to force
>     1kB units.
> - `physical_block_size` is the OS dependent value of an internal block  interface, which may or may not be connected to the underlying hardware. This value is normally 512b or 1k, but is completely dependent on OS.  It can be revealed through the `%B` value on `stat` or `fstat`.  **Note that this value is (almost always) unrelated to the number of physical blocks on a *modern* storage device.**

### Why so confusing?

This number is fairly detached from any physical or meaningful metric.  Many junior programmers haven't had experience with [file holes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315428/how-to-create-a-file-with-file-holes) or [hard/sym links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/why-do-hard-links-seem-to-take-the-same-space-as-the-originals).  In addition, the documentation available on this specific topic is virtually non-existent.

The disjointedness and ambiguity of the term *"block size"* has been a result of numerous different measures being easily confused, and the relatively deep levels of abstraction revolving around disk access.

### Examples of conflicting information:  `du` (or `ls -s`) vs `stat`

Running `du *` in a project folder yields the following: *(Note: `ls -s` returns the same results.)*

```
dactyl:~/p% du *
2       check.cc
2       check.h
1       DONE
3       Makefile
3       memory.cc
5       memory.h
26      p2
4       p2.cc
2       stack.cc
14      stack.h
```

**Total**: 2+2+1+3+3+5+26+4+2+14 = **62 Blocks**

Yet when one runs `stat` we see a different set of values.  Running `stat` in the same directory yields:

```
dactyl:~/p% stat * --printf="%b\t(%B)\t%n: %s bytes\n"
3       (512)   check.cc: 221 bytes
3       (512)   check.h: 221 bytes
1       (512)   DONE: 0 bytes
5       (512)   Makefile: 980 bytes
6       (512)   memory.cc: 2069 bytes
10      (512)   memory.h: 4219 bytes
51      (512)   p2: 24884 bytes
8       (512)   p2.cc: 2586 bytes
3       (512)   stack.cc: 334 bytes
28      (512)   stack.h: 13028 bytes
```

**Total:** 3+3+1+5+6+10+51+8+3+28 = **118 Blocks**

> **Note:** You can use the command `stat * --printf="%b\t(%B)\t%n: %s bytes\n"` > to output (in order) the number of blocks, (in parens) the size of those
>   blocks, the name of the file, and the size in bytes, as shown above.

There are two important things takeaways:

- `stat` reports both the `physical_blocks_in_use` and `physical_block_size` as used in the formula above.  Note that these are values based on OS interfaces.
- `du` is providing what is generally accepted as a fairly accurate *estimate* of physical disk utilization.

---

For reference, here is the `ls -l` of directory above:

```
dactyl:~/p% ls -l
**total 59**
-rw-r--r--. 1 dhs217 grad   221 Oct 16  2013 check.cc
-rw-r--r--. 1 dhs217 grad   221 Oct 16  2013 check.h
-rw-r--r--. 1 dhs217 grad     0 Oct 16  2013 DONE
-rw-r--r--. 1 dhs217 grad   980 Oct 16  2013 Makefile
-rw-r--r--. 1 dhs217 grad  2069 Oct 16  2013 memory.cc
-rw-r--r--. 1 dhs217 grad  4219 Oct 16  2013 memory.h
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 dhs217 grad 24884 Oct 18  2013 p2
-rw-r--r--. 1 dhs217 grad  2586 Oct 16  2013 p2.cc
-rw-r--r--. 1 dhs217 grad   334 Oct 16  2013 stack.cc
-rw-r--r--. 1 dhs217 grad 13028 Oct 16  2013 stack.h
```

Comment: Why I find different result using `du` command. In my case if I using `du *` return in total 20 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 20 + 20 + 4 + 4 = 80
but if just running `du` in same directory give the result 84 ?

Answer (score 28):

That is the total number of file system blocks, including indirect blocks, used by the listed files.  If you run `ls -s` on the same files and sum the reported numbers you'll get that same number.

Comment: This simply is not true.  Example: ```/bin/ls -s``` ->  ```total 15
2 filename  3 filename2  3 filename3  3 filename4  2 filename5  2 filename6  2 filename8  2 filename9```

Comment: I don't know what system you are on, but for me, it *is* true. Example: https://gist.github.com/rfjakob/200f6001bf91cf801891

Comment: @Jakob Posted a full answer, take a look and let me know if that clears it up.

Comment: This is not true in Git bash for Windows.

Comment: I've revised the question in hopes it can be reopened. Hopefully you can vote along...

Answer (score 20):

Just to mention - you can use -h (ls -lh) to convert this in human readable format.

Comment: Unfortunately it also converts all the listed lines to human readable format too.