# How to get the number of files in a folder as a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

Using bash, how can one get the number of files in a folder, excluding directories from a shell script without the interpreter complaining?

With the help of a friend, I've tried

```
$files=$(find ../ -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -n)
$num=$("ls -l" | "grep ^-" | "wc -l")
```

which returns from the command line:

```
../1-prefix_blended_fused.jpg: No such file or directory
ls -l :  command not found
grep ^-: command not found
wc -l:   command not found
```

respectively.  These commands work on the command line, but NOT with a bash script.

Given a file filled with image files formatted like `1-pano.jpg`, I want to grab all the images in the directory to get the largest numbered file to tack onto the next image being processed.

Why the discrepancy?

Comment: What's with the quotes around your commands?

Comment: Also, get rid of the dollar signs when assigning to a variable; `files=$(find ...)` and `num=$( ls -l ... )`.

Comment: @sarnold, several scripting tutorials say that having spaces inside execution blocks is a bad thing, and to use double quotes to alleviate the risk.

Comment: @Jason - Most scripting tutorials you find in the "wild" are junk and teach bad habits. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: So you want a list of files, excluding directories.  What about hard links?  Symlinks?

Comment: @ghoti, the only relevant files will be physically present in the folder.  All directories, links and non-file structures are ignored.

Comment: @chepner, your answer helped the most, as I was coming from PHP and forgot that the dollar sign does not denote an internal variable in bash.

Comment: @Jason - since that is an important criteria for how you will select your answer, it should be in your question, not just in the comments.  Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11131020/edit) and add it, along with any updates showing new research.

Comment: @Jason - okay, how about two hardlinks in the same directory, pointing at the same file?

Comment: @jason: I'd love to see a reference to the guide that proposed `foo=$("ls -l")` was ever a useful thing to do... :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The quotes are causing the error messages.

To get a count of files in the directory:

```
shopt -s nullglob
numfiles=(*)
numfiles=${#numfiles[@]}
```

which creates an array and then replaces it with the count of its elements. This will include files and directories, but not dotfiles or `.` or `..` or other dotted directories.

Use `nullglob` so an empty directory gives a count of 0 instead of 1.

You can instead use `find -type f` or you can count the directories and subtract:

```
# continuing from above
numdirs=(*/)
numdirs=${#numdirs[@]}
(( numfiles -= numdirs ))
```

Also see "[How can I find the latest (newest, earliest, oldest) file in a directory?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)"

You can have as many spaces as you want inside an execution block. They often aid in readability. The only downside is that they make the file a little larger and may slow initial parsing (only) slightly. There are a few places that must have spaces (e.g. around `[`, `[[`, `]`, `]]` and `=` in comparisons) and a few that must not (e.g. around `=` in an assignment.

Comment: bash array are a bit too much for this kind of use !! (the become slow when they are big)

Answer (score 23):

```
ls -l | grep -v ^d | wc -l
```

One line.

Comment: This is not universally correct. This call will in most occasions include a "total <NUM_BLOCKS_ALLOCATED>" line (and thus count one too many, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401704/what-is-that-total-in-the-very-first-line-after-ls-l). Add a wildcard to prevent this:
  ls -l * | grep -v ^d | wc -1

Comment: Well spotted, perhaps: 
 ls -l | grep -v ^d | grep -v ^t | wc -l  then.

Comment: I did a copy/paste of @OliverZendel 's comment, and got an "illegal option" error for wc. The option for wc must be l, not 1 :-)

Comment: I really just wanted to know how many thousands of files were in a directory, so this was close enough for me.

Comment: To exclude symbolic links, you can use ls -l | grep -v ^d | grep -v ^t | grep -v ^l | wc -l .

Comment: Rather than "anti-grepping", just use `ls -l | grep ^- | wc -l`. Only file lines start with `-`.

Answer (score 16):

How about:

```
count=$(find .. -maxdepth 1 -type f|wc -l)
echo $count
let count=count+1 # Increase by one, for the next file number
echo $count
```

Note that this solution is not efficient: it spawns sub shells for the `find` and `wc` commands, but it should work.

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing.  Also, efficiency in microseconds isn't too much of a concern as this command will be run at an interval of roughly 20-40 minutes.

Comment: Exactly; if you use pipelining correctly, none of the spawns will be in the inner loop. Well, they'll all be part of the inner-loop assembly line; but they won't be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 3):

`file_num=$(ls -1 --file-type | grep -v '/$' | wc -l)`

this is a bit lightweight than a find command, and count all files of the current directory.

Comment: For me, `ls -1 --file-type` returns `ls: illegal option -- -`.  If you're going to provide a vendor-specific solution, at least mention the vendor.  Also, this doesn't exclude symlinks.

Answer (score 3):

Simple efficient method:

```
#!/bin/bash
RES=$(find ${SOURCE} -type f | wc -l)
```

Comment: Can you give a brief explanation as to why this works?  Code dumping is (usually) discouraged because the OP may not know enough about the syntax to fully understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Be careful, this does not work if there are file names with linebreaks in them in the directory.

Comment: `RES=$(find ${SOURCE} -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '.' | wc -c)` works regardless of file names characters, since it does not count names but the amount of dot characters printed by find for each found file.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward, reliable way I can think of is using the `find` command to create a reliably countable output.

Counting characters output of `find` with `wc`:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '.' | wc --char
```

or string length of the `find` output:

```sh
a=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '.')
echo ${#a}
```

or using `find` output to populate an arithmetic expression:

```sh
echo $(($(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '+1')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the quotes. The shell is treating them like one file, so it's looking for "ls -l".

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet method which also ignores symlinked directories.

```sh
count=$(ls -l | grep ^- | wc -l)
```

or if you have a target:

```sh
count=$(ls -l /path/to/target | grep ^- | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

REmove the qoutes and you will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the accepted answer (by Dennis W): when I tried this approach I got incorrect counts for dirs without subdirs in Bash 4.4.5.

The issue is that by default nullglob is not set in Bash and `numdirs=(*/)` sets an 1 element array with the glob pattern `*/`. Likewise I suspect `numfiles=(*)` would have 1 element for an empty folder.

Setting `shopt -s nullglob` to disable nullglobbing resolves the issue for me. For an excellent discussion on why nullglob is not set by default on Bash see the answer here: [Why is nullglob not default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204803/why-is-nullglob-not-default/204944#204944)

Note: I would have commented on the answer directly but lack the reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it as a function. Note: you can pass this example, dirs for (directory count), files for files count or "all" for count of everything in a directory. Does not traverse tree as we aren't looking to do that.

```
function get_counts_dir() {

    # -- handle inputs (e.g. get_counts_dir "files" /path/to/folder)
    [[ -z "${1,,}" ]] && type="files" || type="${1,,}"
    [[ -z "${2,,}" ]] && dir="$(pwd)" || dir="${2,,}"

    shopt -s nullglob
    PWD=$(pwd)
    cd ${dir}

    numfiles=(*)
    numfiles=${#numfiles[@]}
    numdirs=(*/)
    numdirs=${#numdirs[@]}

    # -- handle input types files/dirs/or both
    result=0
    case "${type,,}" in
        "files")
            result=$((( numfiles -= numdirs )))
        ;;
        "dirs")
            result=${numdirs}
        ;;
        *)  # -- returns all files/dirs
            result=${numfiles}
        ;;

    esac

    cd ${PWD}
    shopt -u nullglob

    # -- return result --
    [[ -z ${result} ]] && echo 0 || echo ${result}
}
```

Examples of using the function :

```
folder="/home"
get_counts_dir "files" "${folder}"
get_counts_dir "dirs" "${folder}"
get_counts_dir "both" "${folder}"
```

Will print something like :

```
2
4
6
```