# How to view all ( including hidden ) subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ls

On a server when I type in `ls -al` I get a list of the directories

```
-bash-3.2$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    0 Feb 13  2011 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 May 11  2011 ..
drwxr-xr-x 55 torg torg 4096 May 15 05:40 stuff
```

However I happen to know that there are more directories pressent, because when I type `cd loourr` and then go back `cd ..` I find myself with

```
-bash-3.2$ ls -al
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    0 Feb 13  2011 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 May 11  2011 ..
drwxr-xr-x 55 torg torg 4096 May 15 05:40 torg
drwxr-xr-x 108 loourr loourr 20480 Jan 29 19:48 loourr
```

Why is this? I was under the impression that the `-a` flag reveals all directories. What could be causing this, and how can I reveal directories that are still not being listed?

**Update**: 
Heres what happens when I follow David Wolever suggestion

```
-bash-3.2$ ls
torg
-bash-3.2$ pwd
/home/room1
-bash-3.2$ cd loourr
-bash-3.2$ pwd
/home/room1/loourr
-bash-3.2$ cd ..
-bash-3.2$ ls
torg  loourr
-bash-3.2$ pwd
/home/room1
```

and when I mount

```
-bash-3.2$ mount
/dev/sda2 on / type ext3 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sda6 on /scratch type ext3 (rw)
/dev/sda3 on /var type ext3 (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
cartman.foo.bar:/home/room2/me on /home/room2/me type nfs (rw,addr=*.43)
cartman.foo.bar:/home/room2/admin on /home/room2/admin type nfs (rw,addr=*.43)
storage1.foo.bar:/storage/3 on /storage/3 type nfs (rw,nfsvers=3,tcp,intr,hard,addr=*.44)
cartman.foo.bar:/home/room1/torg on /home/room1/torg type nfs (rw,addr=*.43)
cartman.foo.bar:/home/room1/loourr on /home/room1/loourr type nfs (rw,addr=*.43)
```

Some notes: I replaced the server admins name with `admin`, my account name with `me`, the server extension with `foo.bar` and the part of addr= that was constant with `*`

Comment: I think we have a duplicate. Googled "total ls", third result.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401704/what-is-that-total-in-the-very-first-line-after-ls-l

Comment: @Numbers your right, but I've changed the question to more accurately reflect what I'm interested in.

Comment: Next time edit the existing post instead of creating a duplicate, that way all the knowledge presented in the original can be passed along.

Comment: Beware symbolic links...changing directory may not leave you where you thought you were.  Look up the `-L` (logical) and `-P` (physical) options to `cd` command in `bash`.

Comment: Is this part of a challenge of some sort? If so, is it possible that the challenge is doing something funny?

Comment: Alternatively, what filesystem is `/home/room1`? (find out using `mount`).

Comment: It is part of a challenge, so it could quite possible be something tricky/odd. Also I added the mount output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have an automounter set up. This is not a case of directories not being visible, but rather that the directory is created and a remote file system mounted in that location on demand, when you first try to reference the location.

In this case, using `ls -a` or any other option will not show the directories, because they don't exist yet. Your system administrator can set options on the automounter to make the directories visible (browsable), but there are good reasons that they may have not done that, in addition to the fact that it's not usually the default.

Comment: This is interesting. I'm inclined to believe your correct. Is there any way around this? Also do you know of any good resources to learn more about it?

Comment: No way around it without involving your sysadmins, but you can read more via `man automount`, `man autofs`, `man auto.master`, or by googling those terms to find online documentation (if your admins don't install manual pages for whatever reason).

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason that `ls -al` wouldn't show the `loourr` directory.

It must have been created between the first and second calls to `ls`, or you may have ended up in a different directory. Try this:

```
$ ls
stuff/
$ pwd
/foo/
$ cd loourr
$ pwd
/bar/loourr/
$ cd ..
$ ls
stuff/ loourr/
$ pwd
/bar/ <-- different directory
```

There are a couple of different reasons `cd` might take you to a different directory… Symlinks are one (although probably aren't in your case), and the `CDPATH` environment variable is another (if you `echo $CDPATH`, do you see anything?)

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case, can you confirm that this is repeatable and that you end up in the same directory?

Comment: I do end up in the same directory ( /foo/ == /bar/ )

Comment: In that case, can you run the same commands I did in my answer, then copy+paste the terminal session (or take a screen shot) and add that to your question?

Comment: Welp. That's super weird. If you're seeing this repeatably, I'm not sure what it could be, then.

Comment: yeah somehow they're being hidden, some unix trickery. Thanks for your thoughts though