# Direntp current directory shell C

Tags: c, ls, stat

I have a problem with this function :

```
dirp = opendir(ruta);

    if (dirp != NULL){   
        while ((direntp=readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {       
            stat(ruta, &estructura);
```

Sorry for my English ... i hope that you can understand me

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thanks, the funcion works perfectly!

I changed my code for this:

```
while ((direntp=readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {       
                sprintf( cwd, "%s/%s", ruta, direntp->d_name );
                    stat(cwd, &estructura );
```

Thanks for your help and sorry to write here but i cant write a comment in 7 h.
Thanks!!!!!!!

thank you

Comment: OT: The code missed to check the result of the call to `stat()`.

Comment: What `ls` prints in the `total` line is the **sum** of the number of blocks of each file (look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401704/what-is-that-total-in-the-very-first-line-after-ls-l)). You can't get it from a single call of `stat()` but have to add all block sized on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always call `stat` for the directory itself.

This ...:

```
while ((direntp=readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {       
    stat(ruta, &estructura);
    ...
}
```

... should be something like:

```
while ((direntp=readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {       
    char pathname[1024];
    sprintf( pathname, "%s/%s", ruta, direntp->d_name );
    stat( pathname, &estructura );

    ...
}
```

Comment: please help me with st_blocks

Answer (score 2):

It's because you get the information from `stat` for the *directory*, the one you pass to `opendir`.

You have to use that directory as a base, and then append the filenames you get from `readdir`.