# ls -ltr command in UNIX and Linux - Behaviour

Tags: linux, unix, ls

Why does ls -ltr show different total? We have same files in both unix and linux environment please refer BELOW

UNIX

```
> ls -ltr /A/B/C/
total 2140
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       14415 May 30  2007 A.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       11445 May 30  2007 B.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       13443 May 30  2007 C.cab
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo      614429 May 30  2007 D.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo      384763 May 30  2007 E.cab
```

LINUX

```
> ls -ltr /A/B/C/
total 1024
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       14415 May 30  2007 A.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       11445 May 30  2007 B.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo       13443 May 30  2007 C.cab
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo      614429 May 30  2007 D.jar
-rwxr--r--   1 demo     demo      384763 May 30  2007 E.cab
```

PS : I posted the same in superuser, but the view count is very low.. So I am posting here

https://superuser.com/questions/898306/ls-ltr-command-in-unix-and-linux-behaviour

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401704/what-is-that-total-in-the-very-first-line-after-ls-l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of different filesystems. Total shows how many blocks used by files. Add -s and you will see (ls -ltrs)

Comment: Any way to compare the files (just count) of two different Environment?

 I can run a script on both servers to find the count, and compare.

Comment: Quantity of files? Use something like this ls -l | grep -v 'total' |  wc -l

Answer (score 1):

Total only indicates the total count of blocks taken by the directory.And the block size may vary that is why "ls -ltr " is showing different results.