# why ls -l command in linux shows total count? What is that total about?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

ls -l shows the long format of the files and also the permissions. But What the total no. is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7401704/3001761

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you mean the following

```
$ ls -l
total 1408600
...
```

If so the answer can be found in the ls manual.  I get the manual by running `info coreutils 'ls invocation'` on my centos box.

To save you doing that...

```
For each directory that is listed, preface the files with a line
'total BLOCKS', where BLOCKS is the total disk allocation for all
files in that directory.  The block size currently defaults to 1024
bytes, but this can be overridden (*note Block size::).  The BLOCKS
computed counts each hard link separately; this is arguably a
deficiency.
```