# how to make holes in file to erase data by c in linux

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

*Updated: This `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` is not originally supported by `3.0.0-17`, I think I need to patch it.*

I know linux have this `hole` feature, and I am wondering if I could make a hole in a existing file.

For specific, I have created a file named `hole_test` by these codes:

```
 18 #include <stdlib.h>
 19 #include <sys/types.h>
 20 #include <sys/stat.h>
 21 #include <fcntl.h>
 22 #include <unistd.h>
 23 #include <errno.h>
 24 
 25 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 26 {
 27     int fd;
 28     char a[7]="happy!";
 30     fd = open("hole_test", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);
 31     if(fd == -1)
 32             printf("error, %s\n", (char *)strerror(errno));
 35 //  fallocate(fd, 0x02, 0,0);
 36 //  pwrite(fd, a, sizeof(a), 0);
 37 //  pwrite(fd, a, sizeof(b), 65536);
 38     close(fd);
 39     return 0;
 40 }
```

firstly, I user `L36` `L37` to create a file. the `stat hole_test` shows that:

```
  File: `hole_test'
  Size: 65540       Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 1052101     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   bxshi)   Gid: ( 1000/   bxshi)
Access: 2012-04-03 23:02:35.227664608 +0800
Modify: 2012-04-03 23:02:35.227664608 +0800
Change: 2012-04-03 23:02:35.227664608 +0800
```

Then I use `L35` and comment `L36` `L37` to make a hole in my file.(0x02 equals to `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE`, I did not find where it is defined so just use its value)

and then, by `stat hole_test`, the `Blocks` is still 16.

```
  File: `hole_test'
  Size: 65540       Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 1052101     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   bxshi)   Gid: ( 1000/   bxshi)
Access: 2012-04-03 23:02:35.227664608 +0800
Modify: 2012-04-03 23:02:35.227664608 +0800
Change: 2012-04-03 23:02:35.227664608 +0800
```

I want to know if I could make new holes in this `hole_test` file to erase existing data?

How could I make a hole in `hole_test` at offset 0 to 7, in that way I think the `Blocks` could become 8 and the string I wrote would disappear.

Hope you guys could know what I said and give me some advice.

Comment: just tried fopen() and then fseek() to move the cursor to the right offset? After fseek() you can fwrite() to change blocks of data.

Comment: I do not want just change the data, but want to make holes in there. I mean I want to find a way to change this 16 blocks file to 8 blocks.

Comment: This post could help [file hole](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315428/how-to-create-a-file-with-file-holes).

Comment: Note: `man fallocate` ==> "Not all filesystems support FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE; if a filesystem doesn't support the operation, an error is returned." So you may want to check if the underlying FS allows creation of sparse files (hole files).

Answer (score 3):

You use `fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE, offset, len)`. (Supported since Linux 2.6.38) See https://lwn.net/Articles/415889/ for behind-the-scenes details and accompanying patches.

Comment: got a question, where is this `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` defined? I check the `man`, but do not find any header include this constant.

Comment: I find out that `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` is equals to `0x02`, so I tried `fallocate(fd, FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE, 0, 7);`. And it is still 16 blocks. No difference on that. Do I need to patch this manually? I am using 3.x Kernel.

Comment: Check the return and error code from `fallocate`. As mentioned in the link, only a few filesystems support it.

Comment: yes, thanks. I checked it, and the `errno` indicates that `Operation not supported` The fs of my hd is `EXT4`. And the `man 2 fallocate` only have one flag `FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE`.

Comment: @bxshi `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` MUST be OR'ed with the `FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE0` flag . You cannot decrease a filesize with FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE

Answer (score 0):

According to the [man page for fallocate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html):

> The FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE flag must be ORed with FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE
>          in mode; in other words, even when punching off the end of the file,
>          the file size (as reported by stat(2)) does not change.

[At least on ext4](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/extents.c?v=3.14#L4567), if you just pass `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE`, `fallocate()` will return `Operation not supported`.

Also note that:

> The FALLOC_FL_* flags are
>          defined in glibc headers only since version 2.18.

So you may need to manually define them if you're using a supported kernel with an earlier version of libc:

```
// Constants are defined in glibc >= 2.18
#define FALLOC_FL_KEEP_SIZE    0x1
#define FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE   0x2
```