# What does total size in stat command output refer to physical or logical size?

Tags: linux

stats command gives following output -

```
bash-3.2$ stat myfile.zip
  File: `myfile.zip'
  Size: 80195           Blocks: 168        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 24675915    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  501/meghadata)   Gid: (  500/   megha)
Access: 2013-12-24 10:53:39.000000000 +0530
Modify: 2013-10-01 18:00:58.000000000 +0530
Change: 2013-12-24 10:51:39.000000000 +0530
```

Does that 'Size' refer to physical size or logical size?

Answer (score 1):

I think Size refers to the logical size.

Look, `stat` uses the system call `lstat` (as shown by `strace`).

```
lstat("myfilename.txt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1000000, ...}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 4), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f52e3d08000
write(1, "  File: `myfilename.txt'\n", 25) = 25
write(1, "  Size: 1000000   \tBlocks: 1968 "..., 68) = 68
write(1, "Device: 1eh/30d\tInode: 908841   "..., 44) = 44
```

man lstat:

> these system calls return a stat structure, which contains the
>   following fields:
>
> off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */   blkcnt_t 
>   st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
>
> The st_size field gives the size of the file (if it is a regular file
>   or a symbolic link) in bytes. The st_blocks field indicates the number
>   of blocks allocated to the file, 512-byte units.  (This may be smaller
>   than st_size/512 when the file has holes.)

So "st_blocks field indicates the number of blocks allocated to the file, 512-byte units." My file is 1,000,000 bytes in lenght. However it has 1968 blocks that means 1,007,616 bytes.

Moreoever there are files with holes "This may be smaller than st_size/512 when the file has holes". So you can create a file which physically use less space on filesystem than show by `ls -l`. For example in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5315473/184968
it is shown how to create a file with holes:

```
>dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4096 count=2 of=file_with_holes
>dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4096 seek=7 count=2 of=file_with_holes

>stat file_with_holes
File: `file_with_holes'
Size: 36864           Blocks: 40         IO Block: 65536  regular file
```

Its logical size is 36,864 bytes while its takes only 20,480 bytes on filesystem (40*512 = 20480 bytes).