# Create a sparse file

Tags: linux, file

I tried `lseek` and `dd if=/dev/urandom seek=7 bs=4096 count=2 of=fwh`, they didn't work on my computer. The `ls -lks` result is: 
`44 -rw-rw-r-- 1 guangmu guangmu 36864 Aug 10 18:19 fwh`.

I tried `rm` the file, `reboot`, and even cleaning the blocks used by fwt via `debugfs`. These didn't help.

My filesystem is ext4, OS is ubuntu 14.04. Here is the result of `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda5`:

> ```
> tune2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
> Filesystem volume name:   
> Last mounted on:          /
> Filesystem UUID:          e051336c-6a7a-4683-9c24-1230676170b1
> Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
> Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
> Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
> Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
> Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
> Filesystem state:         clean
> Errors behavior:          Continue
> Filesystem OS type:       Linux
> Inode count:              34594816
> Block count:              138359808
> Reserved block count:     6917990
> Free blocks:              109566416
> Free inodes:              33280312
> First block:              0
> Block size:               4096
> Fragment size:            4096
> Reserved GDT blocks:      991
> Blocks per group:         32768
> Fragments per group:      32768
> Inodes per group:         8192
> Inode blocks per group:   512
> Flex block group size:    16
> Filesystem created:       Mon Jan 20 20:56:20 2014
> Last mount time:          Mon Aug 11 11:08:31 2014
> Last write time:          Mon Aug 11 11:08:30 2014
> Mount count:              387
> Maximum mount count:      -1
> Last checked:             Mon Jan 20 20:56:20 2014
> Check interval:           0 ()
> Lifetime writes:          743 GB
> Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
> Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
> First inode:              11
> Inode size:              256
> Required extra isize:     28
> Desired extra isize:      28
> Journal inode:            8
> First orphan inode:       18877404
> Default directory hash:   half_md4
> Directory Hash Seed:      780cc1b8-1fa1-4751-9385-270b563b29cd
> Journal backup:           inode blocks
> ```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is correct. You have `seek`ed (or sought maybe?) 7 blocks of 4096 bytes in `fwh` and then written 2 blocks of 4096 bytes to it. So you would expect `fwh` to contain 9 blocks of 4096 bytes, which is 36,864 bytes - exactly as you have.

Or have I missed something? What were you expecting?

Comment: According to APUE Section 3.6, if I `lseek` out of the end of a file, a sparse file will be made, and the actual blocks it occupied should be fewer than the file size. However it didn't work on my computer. I `lseek` 7 blocks and wrote 2 blocks with block-size=4096, and the `ls -lks` is `44 -rw-rw-r-- 1 guangmu guangmu 36864 Aug 10 18:19 fwh`. For more detail, you can see ["how-to-create-a-file-with-file-holes"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315428/how-to-create-a-file-with-file-holes), it also didn't work on my computer.

Comment: Ok. I am using OSX HFS+ filesystem which doesn't support sparse files, so mine is correct. What filesystem are you using and what is your blocksize? `df -g <filesystem of fhw>` and/or `fstyp -v /dev/dsk/something`

Comment: And while you are getting the FS type and blocksize, can you remove your file, re-run your `dd` command and re-run your `ls -lks` command and post the results please? Preferably do all that by 'editing your original question` rather than inside `Comments`. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my question, and I tried according to your suggestions, but the result didn't change. Thanks.@MarkSetchell

Comment: That is odd. Your blocksize is 4096 and your `dd` command has caused 44 blocks to be allocated on disk, whereas you would expect it to be 2 blocks, or at the very most, 9. I would try some experiments with `seek` set to 0,8,64,256, 1024 and see how the number of allocated blocks changes, to see if there is a straight-line relationship or what is going on.

Comment: I found the reason, it's my carelessness. while `/dev/sda5`(/) is a ext4 filesystem, `/home` is encrypted with `ecryptfs`(maybe it's default on Ubuntu?). I retried in another path, a sparse file was created. Thanks for your help!@MarkSetchell

Comment: Aha! That makes sense - good! We don't like unsolved mysteries :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's my carelessness.:(

`/home` is mounted as ecrpyptfs, which doesn't support sparse file.