# How to efficiently allocate a file of predefined size and fill it with a non-zero value using Python?

Tags: python, linux, windows, file, bigdata

I'm writing a program that uses dynamic programming to solve a difficult problem. The DP solution requires storing a large table. The full table occupies approximately 300 Gb. Physically it is stored in 40 ~7Gb files. I'm marking unused table entries with the byte `\xFF`. I'd like to allocate space for this table quickly. The program will have to run both under Windows and Linux.

In short, I want to efficiently create large files filled with a specific byte in a cross-platform manner.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
def reset_storage(self, path):
    fill = b'\xFF'

    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        for _ in range(3715948544 * 2):
            f.write(fill)
```

It takes it about 40 minutes to create one 7 Gb file. How do I speed it up?

I've taken a look at other questions, but none of them seem to be relevant:

- [Allocate a file of particular size in Linux with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149494/allocate-a-file-of-particular-size-in-linux-with-python) — no answer
- [create file of particular size in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816059/create-file-of-particular-size-in-python) — file is filled with `\0` or solution is Windows-only
- [How to create a file with a given size in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139261/how-to-create-a-file-with-a-given-size-in-linux) — all solutions are Linux-specific

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write blocks, not bytes, and avoid iterating huge `range`s for no reason.

```
import itertools

def reset_storage(self, path):
    total = 3715948544 * 2
    block_size = 4096  # Tune this if needed, just make sure it's a factor of the total
    fill = b'\xFF' * block_size

    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.writelines(itertools.repeat(fill, total // block_size))
        # If you want to handle initialization of arbitrary totals without
        # needing to be careful that block_size evenly divides total, add
        # a single:
        # f.write(fill[:total % block_size])
        # here to write out the incomplete block.
```

Ideal block size is going to differ from system to system. One reasonable choice would be to use `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` to match writes to flushes automatically, while still keeping memory usage low.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is calling python methods way to often (for each byte!). What I offer is surely not perfect, but will work many, many times faster. Try the following:

```
fill = b"\xFF" * 1024 * 1024  # instantly 1 MiB of ones
...
file_size = 300 * 1024  # in MiB now!
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    for _ in range(file_size):
        f.write(fill)
```