# How do you programmatically create a completely empty sparse file on linux?

Tags: c, linux, sparse-file

If you run dd with this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=sparsefile bs=1 count=0 seek=1048576
```

You appear to get a completely unallocated sparse file (this is ext4)

```
smark@we:/sp$ ls -ls sparsefile 
0 -rw-rw-r-- 1 smark smark 1048576 Nov 24 16:19 sparsefile
```

fibmap agrees:

```
smark@we:/sp$ sudo hdparm --fibmap sparsefile 
sparsefile:
 filesystem blocksize 4096, begins at LBA 2048; assuming 512 byte sectors.
 byte_offset  begin_LBA    end_LBA    sectors
```

Without having to dig through the source of dd, I'm trying to figure out how to do that in C.

I tried fseeking and fwriting zero bytes, but it did nothing.
Not sure what else to try, I figured somebody might know before I hunt down dd's innards.

EDIT: including my example...

```
FILE *f = fopen("/sp/sparse2", "wb");
fseek(f, 1048576, SEEK_CUR);
fwrite("x", 1, 0, f);
fclose(f);
```

Comment: `dd` is open source. grab the source and look through it...

Comment: you must have missed the part about "without having to dig through the source of dd". I figured somebody might just know.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question but are you looking for `touch <filename>`?

Comment: @jshaw.fb: that just creates a 0byte file. sparse files occpuy as much space as you want, without actually using up disk space. it's like putting "reserved for..." on the disk blocks without actually using them.

Comment: Normally you'd use `lseek` to a point beyond the current end of file, then write something. I'd be surprised if `fseek` didn't use `lseek`. Can you show the code that you're using?

Comment: From running `strace`, I see that `dd` adds a call to `ftruncate`. That'll create a sparse file even if you don't do any `write`s.

Comment: ahhhh.. good idea, I didn't think to try strace, and yes, ftruncate will do it. make it an answer and I'll accept, thanks.

Comment: Your code tells fwrite to write zero bytes, so it doesn't write anything. Change the 0 to 1 and it'll work.

Comment: if I change it to 1 it writes an entire block, that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: use which dd or whereis dd to find dd.  strings /usr/bin/dd |sort -u |less, shows various function calls. and man <function> will explain the functions used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file with file holes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315428/how-to-create-a-file-with-file-holes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write to a file using `write` or various library routines that ultimately call `write`, there's a *file offset pointer* associated with the file descriptor that determines where in the file the bytes will go. It's normally positioned at the end of the data that was processed by the most recent call to `read` or `write`. But you can use [`lseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lseek.html) to position the pointer anywhere within the file, and even beyond the current end of the file. When you write data at a point beyond the current EOF, the area that was skipped is conceptually filled with zeroes. Many systems will optimize things so that any whole filesystem blocks in that skipped area simply aren't allocated, producing a *sparse file*. Attempts to read such blocks will succeed, returning zeroes.

Writing block-sized areas full of zeroes to a file generally won't produce a sparse file, although it's possible for some filesystems to do this.

Another way to produce a sparse file, used by GNU dd, is to call `ftruncate`. The [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ftruncate.html) says this:

> The ftruncate() function causes the regular file referenced by fildes to have a size of length bytes.
>
> If the file previously was larger than length, the extra data is discarded. If it was previously shorter than length, it is unspecified whether the file is changed or its size increased. **If the file is extended, the extended area appears as if it were zero-filled.**

Support for sparse files is filesystem-specific, although virtually all designed-for-UNIX local filesystems support them.

Comment: You just beat me to it!

Comment: zfs does that by the way, writing chunks of contiguous zeroes to a file (if any compression scheme is on) will basically hole punch that area back into sparseness.

Comment: @stu Thanks for that - I was hoping that people with expertise in various filesystem types would comment. I'll add the additional info to my answer after a few days.

Answer (score 9):

This is complementary to the answer by @[MarkPlotnick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33904633/1983495), it's a sample simple implementation of the feature you requested using `ftruncate()`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int file;
    int mode;

    mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
    file = open("sparsefile", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, mode);
    if (file == -1)
        return -1;
    ftruncate(file, 0x100000);
    close(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The use of `fchmod()` here is not recommended, since it bypasses `umask`.  The mode should be passed to `open()`.

Comment: Here, I've fixed it.  `mode` is the third parameter to `open()`.

Comment: Thanks for posting an example - add parsing command line for filename and size and it would be a useful utility.